# Maximum Height in DIV

Tags: html, css

I am having problems getting my main content div to stretch to full height, the other container is able to stretch to full height.

http://westcountrycreamteas.co.uk/test.html

Is the page I am trying to stretch down and the div that is having problems is inner.

Comment: which is the main container? can you give me its class/id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
#para {
    margin-left: 10%;
    height:999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

but i think,the content area shallstretch depending on the content.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CPfyL/

Comment: yeah the area stretches as you add more content in it. However, if you want to force a fixed stretching, you should apply a fixed height. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
height: auto !important
```

from your container div #outer.

Should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have sorted the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want max-height :

```
div{
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: add this to style:
height:100%;
and remove the max-height line

Comment: heights cannot be issued with a percentage afaik.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your outer div. You have set its height using a percentage, but heights can only be set using px. What should you do:

- Set the outer div height to a desirable amount, eg: `height: 900px;`
- Set the height of the div you're talking about the same as the outer's one.